# Annabels ants Maths Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

So, I need help with this question, it has been posted on this site before but I couldn't understand it, here it is.

> Annabel made a shape by placing identical square tiles in a frame as shown in the diagram above. The tiles are arranged in columns. Each column touches the base but no columns touch the side or top. There are no empty gaps between columns. The frame can be enlarged as needed.
>
> D. Show four arrangements of 137 tiles, each arrangement with a different maximum height, so that the ant walks a total of 34 tile edges.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @AugSB This is definitely a duplicate of the question you posted, It is a verbatim duplicate. However while the accepted answer gives the answer it is not necessarily clear how he answered it.

Comment: @zen: We should have better answers to that one, then.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, I agee, I also voted to flag it as duplicate.